# I want an image to be shown in a circle but when it is hovered on the circle gets bigger until the whole image is seen

Tags: html, css, image

I have this image and I want it to be shown in a small circle and then when hovered on the circle to get bigger and bigger until the whole image is shown. I hope this image helps https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWo7U.jpg.

Comment: what have you tried to achieve that so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code **i.e.** [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your img element in a container
Then apply a `object-fit: cover;` to your img.

After you just have to apply hover effect on your container to make animation and circle

Thanks to [this tuto](http://www.coding-dude.com/wp/css/css-circle-image/#:%7E:text=Make%20a%20Circle%20Image%20with%20CSS%20clip%2Dpath&text=One%20of%20the%20values%20for,and%20with%20a%20specified%20center.), before ask questions try to check on google

```css
.circle-image{
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transition: all .2s;
}
.circle-image:hover{
  border-radius:0;
}

.circle-image img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<span class="circle-image">
 <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1657299170237-2d4cd59b5156?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80"/>
</span>
```

Comment: I do know how to achieve this effect but I want the circle to be smaller just like in the example provided and I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport"
              content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            .image-container {
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;
                border-radius: 50%;
                transition-property: border-radius;
                transition-duration: 2s;
            }
      
            .image-container:hover {
                border-radius: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img class="image-container"
             src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1581833971358-2c8b550f87b3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1742&q=80"
             alt="">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).